# How do I intercept all udp packets and redirect them to a proxy?

Tags: networking, internet, proxy, tunnel, udp

System: win10 64bit .

I want to positively intercept all UDP packets and then tunnel them through a proxy 127.0.0.1:29918, so they will all have to go through this proxy in order to reach the outside world.

How do I do that? Any software for it? I remember for TCP packets, there is proxifier, but I don't know about UDP ones.

Comment: Software recommendations are off topic herr.

Comment: Oh yea? I'm asking a very specific question and I didn't ask for any software in particular.

Comment: let me quote your post to clarify the off-topic bit - "Any software for it".  I don't neccessarily like the "no software recommendations rule", but baddies.   You might want to modify the last paragraph to remove the second sentence, which would not remove much from the question but would make it on-topic.